# Light migration one-to-one to one-to-many

Tags: ios, core-data

It is possible to make a light migration of a one-to-one relationship to a one-to-many relationship. The schema is correctly updated. Ie A->B becomes A->>B

But the ont-to-one reference in A->B is lost. I was expecting to access B after the migration but it is now a zombie without anyone referencing it.

Do I have to create a mapping model for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a mapping model will trigger a heavy weight migration.  Heavy migrations are very slow and memory intensive.  If you are running on iOS then you do not want to do that.

If the automatic migration is failing then you probably want to do an export/import type migration instead of a heavy migration.

Essentially for a export/import migration you walk through your existing Core Data model and export it out to some other format (I like to use JSON) and then import it back into the new data model.

If you are on the desktop, then you can definitely use a heavy migration.  The desktop has far more memory available, a larger CPU, etc.

### Update

> I thought of that but it is complicated. I have to first export when the app starts. Then change the model version of the xcdatamodelid to the next version programatically. Then let the light migration do its work. Then import. For each app launch after that I have to check if the model version is the latest so I know to migrate or not.

Yes it is complicated although that is not how you would do it.  The other option is to perform a heavy weight migration which risks popping memory, popping the watch dogs and takes longer thus creating a poor user experience.

If the lightweight migration can't do something then a heavy migration or manual migration is required.  A heavy migration (with a mapping model) is not designed for iOS.  It is a carry over from the OS X days. Yes you can get it to work but it is not performant.

Doing a manual migration is not that difficult.  As part of your start up procedure, you should be checking for a migration event anyway.  If a migration event occurs then you proceed into the manual migration by standing up the old stack using the old model. `NSManagedObjectModel` has methods to resolve this. Then you export to JSON, stand up the new stack and import.

Comment: I thought of that but it is complicated. I have to first export when the app starts. Then change the model version of the xcdatamodelid to the next version programatically. Then let the light migration do its work. Then import. For each app launch after that I have to check if the model version is the latest so I know to migrate or not.

Comment: Why can't you use multiple passes to reduce the memory overhead?

Comment: Good explanation. Nice to hear that mapping model is not designed for iOS. I need to get more info on best practices for manual migration then. I did not know about any migration event (is that a notification) or working with two NSManagedObjectModels at the same time. Which methods are you referring to? Any links to more info or tutorials on manual migration would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @HeathBorders you can but working with heavy migration is an arcane practice that is not documented.  There are very few people outside of Apple that understand it.  It is best avoided on iOS. When you write your own manual migration and still need a multi-pass migration you then own and understand the code to make that happen.

Comment: @Jump look at the documentation on the `NSManagedObjectModel` and you will find `-isConfiguration:compatibleWithStoreMetadata:` and `+mergedModelFromBundles: forStoreMetadata:`. With those in hand it should be straight forward on how to stand up the old stack and then the new stack.